# Create content of certain content type based on outside information/validation

Tags: nodes

I'm running a game server. This server is updated ever so often and I want my players to be informed about the update.

I want this to happen automatically. What I have is some JSON output I can query for changes to the version of the server. If there is a valid response (an update occurred) I want to create an article on my website.

Can articles be created based on outside check and subsequently be filled with some data from these JSON responses?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you using Drupal 7 or 8?